# Show SKU on cart and checkout pages in Woocommerce 3

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, checkout, cart

I would like to display SKU on cart (Under product column ) and checkout page.

I searched SO, but all answers are for old versions of WooCommerce and non of them is for 3.x.

How can I show SKU on cart and checkout pages in Woocommerce 3?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

2021 Update

You can do it with a custom unction hooked in **`woocommerce_cart_item_name`** action hook, this way:

```
// Display the sku below cart item name
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_item_name', 'display_sku_after_item_name', 5, 3 );
function display_sku_after_item_name( $item_name, $cart_item, $cart_item_key ) {
    $product = $cart_item['data']; // The WC_Product Object

    if( is_cart() && $product->get_sku() ) {
        $item_name .= '<br><span class="item-sku">'. $product->get_sku() . '</span>';
    }
    return $item_name;
}

// Display the sku below under cart item name in checkout
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_cart_item_quantity', 'display_sku_after_item_qty', 5, 3 );  
function display_sku_after_item_qty( $item_quantity, $cart_item, $cart_item_key ) {
    $product = $cart_item['data']; // The WC_Product Object

    if( $product->get_sku() ) {
        $item_quantity .= '<br><span class="item-sku">'. $product->get_sku() . '</span>';
    }
    return $item_quantity;
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.*

This code is tested and works on WooCommerce 3+. You will get:

[image]

And

[image]

Related similar: [How to Show SKU with product title in Order received page and Email order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46117929/how-to-show-sku-with-product-title-in-order-received-page-and-email-order/46121630#46121630)

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
I added the code to the functions.php of my active theme but the SKU is still not showing. 
My product is variable product and all variables have different SKU, but I guess that should not matter. Any other tips?

Comment: So easy. Thanks!

Comment: Just tried this with WooCommerce 6.3.1. Worked perfectly!

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to do some template overrides.

**Cart**

Copy `plugins/woocommerce/templates/cart/cart.php` into your theme file at `my_theme/woocommerce/cart/cart.php` if it isn't already there. Then add the following at approx line #85

```
// Meta data
//  (this is already in cart.php; look for it for where to place the next snippet)
echo WC()->cart->get_item_data( $cart_item );

// Add SKU below product name
if ( !empty($_product->get_sku()) ) { ?>
<div class="sku">
    <small><?php echo "SKU: ". $_product->get_sku(); ?></small>
</div>
<?php }
```

**Checkout**

Copy `plugins/woocommerce/templates/checkout/review-order.php` into your theme file at `my_theme/woocommerce/checkout/review-order.php` if it isn't already there. Then add the following at approx line #43

```
<?php
//  (this is already in review-order.php; look for it for where to place the next snippet)
echo WC()->cart->get_item_data( $cart_item ); ?>

<?php
// Add SKU below product name
if ( !empty($_product->get_sku()) ) { ?>
<div class="sku">
    <small><?php echo "SKU: ". $_product->get_sku(); ?></small>
</div>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: I tried this already and the SKU is not displaying. 
Thanks or your answer!

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with this way:

```
/**
 * @snippet       Show SKU @ WooCommerce Cart
 * @author        Khalid Almallahi
 */

add_action( 'woocommerce_after_cart_item_name', 'abukotsh_sku_below_cart_item_name', 11, 2 );

function abukotsh_sku_below_cart_item_name( $cart_item, $cart_item_key ) {
    $_product = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_product', $cart_item['data'], $cart_item, $cart_item_key );
    $sku = $_product->get_sku();
    if ( ! $sku ) return;
    echo '<p><small>SKU: ' . $sku . '</small></p>';
}
```