# How to Show SKU with product title in Order received page and Email order

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, orders

In functions.php

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_add_order_item_meta', 'custom_add_item_sku', 10, 3 );
function custom_add_item_sku( $item_id, $values, $cart_item_key ) {

 $item_sku = get_post_meta( $values[ 'product_id' ], '_sku', true );

 wc_add_order_item_meta( $item_id, 'SKU', $item_sku , false );

}
```

But its showing SKU value below Product title but i want it like this

> > SKU:123sd - Product Name

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Update 2018-04-01 - Changing of hook and Improved code.

Use woocommerce_order_item_name filter hook instead. I have make some changes in your code:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_order_item_name', 'sku_before_order_item_name', 30, 3 );
function sku_before_order_item_name( $item_name, $item, $is_visible ) {
    $product = $item->get_product();
    $sku = $product->get_sku();

    // When sku doesn't exist we exit
    if( empty( $sku ) ) return $item_name;

    $sku_text = __( 'SKU', 'woocommerce' ) . ': ' . $sku;

    // Add product permalink when argument $is_visible is true
    $product_permalink =  $is_visible ? $product->get_permalink( $item ) : '';

    if( $product_permalink )
        return sprintf( '<a href="%s">%s - %s</a>', $product_permalink, $sku_text, $item->get_name() );
    else
        return $sku_text . ' - ' . $item->get_name();
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.*

Tested in WooCommerce 3+ and works.

---

Displaying the SKU in cart items name *(Updated: with the link for cart page)*:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_item_name', 'sku_before_cart_item_name', 10, 3 );
function sku_before_cart_item_name( $product_name, $cart_item, $cart_item_key ) {
    $product =  $cart_item['data'];
    $sku = $product->get_sku();

    // When sku doesn't exist we exit
    if( empty( $sku ) ) return $product_name;

    $sku_text = __( 'SKU', 'woocommerce' ) . ': ' . $sku;
    $product_permalink = $product->get_permalink( $cart_item );

    if ( is_cart() )
        return sprintf( '<a href="%s">%s - %s</a>', esc_url( $product_permalink ), $sku_text, $product->get_name() );
    else
        return $sku_text . ' - ' . $product_name;
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.*

Tested in WooCommerce 3+ and works.

Answer (score 0):

I would change the hook to 'woocommerce_new_order_item' as it seems like there may be some deprecation issues with the 'woocommerce_add_order_item_meta'

Something like this should add the name after the SKU, but I don't know if that's exactly what you're looking for.

```
    add_action( 'woocommerce_new_order_item', 'custom_add_item_sku', 10, 3 );
    function custom_add_item_sku( $item_id, $values, $cart_item_key ) {
     $item_sku = get_post_meta( $values[ 'product_id' ], '_sku', true );
     $name = = $values['name'];
     wc_add_order_item_meta( $item_id, 'SKU', $item_sku . ' - ' . $name , false );
    }
```